# Is there a way to extract a picture from an excel file using R? It could then be placed into the tesseract ocr

Tags: r, excel, tesseract

I have multiple excel files with pictures in one of the sheets. Is there a way to extract the image (image path) into R to then be placed into the tesseract ocr.

Previously I used the openxlsx package's function loadWorkbook:

```
wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook("C:/Users/.../test_file.xlsx")
```

when you output wb:

```
A Workbook object.

Worksheets:
 Sheet 1: "Sheet1"



Images:
 Image 1: "C:/Users/..../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuUQZm7//file41e..._openxlsx_loadworkbook/xl/media/image1.png"
 Worksheet write order: 1
```

Is there anyway to get this image path? The type variable is a workbook object and when you do type of it is "S4" so it appears that I can't convert it to a character and pull out the path.

Comment: important to know: an Excel file is "just" a zipped XML file. you might try unzipping it and looking for a media folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the image path with the `@media` slot of your workbook object.

Here's a reprex of plotting a PNG stored within an xlsx file:

```r
require(png)
require(openxlsx)
require(grid)

wb  <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook("~/img.xlsx")
img <- png::readPNG(wb@.xData$media[1])
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the information! The media part of the workbook was what I was looking for but the image building is really interesting and will also be helpful in the future.